# Watch C# code while debugging in vscode

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, watch

I have created a new mvc angular app using the "dotnet new angular". By default this is set up to package the client side files using webpack and watch them so while debugging if I change a client side file and save it in vscode the page in chrome is automatically refreshed to reflect the changes. I am able to get a similar behavior for back end C# code by running "dotnet watch run" from the terminal but then I can't debug. Does anyone know how I can configure vscode to automatically watch the back end C# files while debugging so that changing the code will result in an automatic rebuild?

Comment: That won’t be possible. Debugging is a separate state from editing your code, that requires attaching to the running program. You generally shouldn’t debug _all the time_, just debug when you actually need to debug stuff.

Comment: Still can't do this now in VsCode in May 2023. But it is possible in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I run two instances of VSCode, one from the ClientApp folder, and one from the C# project root.
In the C# project, the .vscode/tasks.json contains this:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        // binds to CTRL + SHIFT + B (Build)
        "label": "watch",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "args": [
            "watch",
            "run"
        ],
        "isBackground": true,
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

and in .vscode/launch.json I have this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

so CTRL+SHIFT+B builds the code and starts dotnet watch run, then F5 launches a browser once you choose the process ( [project-name].dll )